# Example of group variety which has index 2 subgroup

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-groups

I'm looking for a example of group variety which has index 2 connected subgroup.
My most familiar example of group variety is elliptic curves, but it is connected itself, is there some example of group variety which has nontrivial connected component ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Orthogonal groups?

Comment: Take any connected group variety $G$ (you can even take $G=1$), then take the product with the discrete group variety of order $2$.